# Unable to determine the actor in UCP estimation for a given scenario

Tags: estimation

I have just started using [Use Case Points](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/estimation_techniques/estimation_techniques_use_case_points.htm) recently. Apparently it looks simple to use but there are certain scenarios where it is difficult to figure out the right transaction count or actor count.

I am facing similar problem where a batch job is trigger internally. Then who is going to be the actor in this case? The user group from which is batch job is triggered or the batch job scheduler. I think the batch job itself can not be the actor here because for any transaction some actor must be there right? Your opinion would really help me to understand the matter in depth

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about user goal level scenario then primary actor is the system itself. Scheduler can be secondary actor starting the case or its trigger.

If we are talking about subfunction level scenario then it can have some part of the system like job processor as primary actor and system job engine as secondary actor starting the use case or being its trigger.